# Is there any project planning software out there for Windows that doesn't look ugly?

Tags: pm-software, time-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any project planning software out there for Windows that doesn't look ugly?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/3291/is-there-any-project-planning-software-out-there-for-windows-that-doesnt-look-u)

I realize this may sound biased, but I really like Windows in some respects. I just have been spoiled by Apple for so long that if something looks like it was designed by a programmer instead of a designer, I can't bring myself to use it on a daily basis. I've looked at all kinds of options, even the expensive ones like Microsoft Project. They all boast the same sparse interface, populated with thin, hard-to-see bars that are drawn in flat colors from a very limited palette. Has anyone found something that they enjoy using that looks a little more... I don't know... together? Professional?